# Programming a demo of a web app in jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins

We are deploying some small web apps.

UI design is quite hard if done right, so lacking resources, we are now looking for a simple way to bring the casual user up to speed (with our bad design ;)).

Are there jQuery plugins that could be used to create a demo? (fire events, move dialogs, etc. etc. ?)

Should we use a totally different approach?

Comment: The app is already in production. We don't want to show future functionality. Its more a tutorial for casual users.

Comment: To clarify, do you already know about jQuery UI?  http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do mockups using something like [balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) - that way the customer doesn't think it's further along than it actually is.

Comment: Hey I neede to clarify my question. As the tutorial must live in a production app.
But balsamiq IS cute, I've already started using it to describe use cases :)